# How to differentiate between two REST requests to give different responses

Tags: xml, rest, mocking, request, soapui

I'm new to REST and here's my question 
I have two requests and i have a mock server that responds to those requests .
My problem is that i can't differentiate between the first and second request 
I've thought about using their names as an identifier but every attempt i try to make to get the name ends up       with fail 
Any help would be greatly appreciated 
Thanks in advance 
Here's some stuff that can help you guys 
This is a request instance

```
POST https://<GOSURL>/1/smsmessaging/outbound/%2B33688663346/subscriptions
HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: AUTH
transEnd="1",FA="tel:+22515012345678",linkId="",SAN="",transactionId="",spId="98
76543210",spPassword="c0d8004ab8acb3472b084e591dd3f784",timeStamp="1111111111",p
roductId="98765432100004"
User-Agent: Jakarta Commons-HttpClient/3.1
Host: 10.99.163.149:7601
Content-Length: 127
{"notifyURL":"http://90.27.20.111:3005/restSmsService/delivery",
"clientCorrelator":"6666",
"callbackData":"callFunction()"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

hi there  you can try adding a custom header something like X-service1 and set the value to and identifying feature and then later check for the same header to diiferentiate.

hope this helps

Comment: The requests instances are not mine to change , i have to work around it

Comment: The requests come to me defined by company that i'm working for , they come in some formats that i'm not able to change so i have to work around getting the name

Comment: what about the server do you have access to it , can you play around over there

Answer (score 0):

Can you change urls to your mock service in requests? If so, you can just create two different mocks - one for each request.